# Changing CSS of something using DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom, firefox-addon

I am actually trying to develop a Firefox Plugin. And I need to Dynamically Change The CSS of the Icon.

How do I do that for this CSS

```
#sample-button              {list-style-image: url("chrome://sample    /skin/sample24.png");}
toolbar[iconsize="small"]   #sample-button  {list-style-image: url("chrome://sample/skin/sample16.png");}
```

I want to change the CSS of toolbar[iconsize="small"] #sample button. 
I can change the css of sample button by simply doing

```
document.getElementById("sample-button").style.listStyleImage = url('chrome://sample/skin/sample_change24.png')
```

But I don't knw how to do it for the second part that is in square brackets [].

Waiting for The Answer,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector('[iconsize="small"] #sample-button').style.listStyleImage = '...';
```